# finding integer declared variables in ELF executable using a hex editor

Tags: elf, hex, hex-editors

i want to change the value of an integer declared variable in an executable, by using the hex editor only suppose i know that there's a variable type int declared in the code and the variable is this:

> int value = 1337;

i want to edit the executable using a hex editor search for the value 1337 and change it to something else, i tried ghex in ubuntu but i don't know how to search for it i converted it to hexadecimal but i didn't find it, thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

First, you would use `readelf` to determine the virtual address of the variable (where it lives in memory after the program is loaded). `-s` will show you the symbol table, and we'll grep for the name of your variable.

```
readelf -s a.out | grep value
```

This will output a line that looks like:

```
    64: 000000000060102c     4 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT   24 value
```

So here, the 64th symbol in the file is `value`. Its load address is 0x60102c, and it's 4 bytes in size. Now we have the *virtual address*, but this doesn't tell us where it's at in the file. To do that, we need to do three things:

1. Figure out which *section* it's in,
2. Figure out this value's *section offset*
3. Add its section offset to that section's *file offset*, to get your item's actual *file offset* (the "address" you would see in a hex editor, if you opened the ELF file).

Let's run `readelf` again. `-S` will list the sections.

```
readelf -S a.out
```

Here's a snippet of the output. Remember the address of our variable is at `60102c`, and we're looking for the section where `60102c` lies between its `Address` and its `Address + Size`.  Since this is a read-write variable, we can take a guess that it will be in the `.data` section.

```
Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type             Address           Offset
       Size              EntSize          Flags  Link  Info  Align
  ...
  [21] .dynamic          DYNAMIC          0000000000600e28  00000e28
       00000000000001d0  0000000000000010  WA       6     0     8
  [22] .got              PROGBITS         0000000000600ff8  00000ff8
       0000000000000008  0000000000000008  WA       0     0     8
  [23] .got.plt          PROGBITS         0000000000601000  00001000
       0000000000000028  0000000000000008  WA       0     0     8
  [24] .data             PROGBITS         0000000000601028  00001028
       0000000000000008  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     4
  [25] .bss              NOBITS           0000000000601030  00001030
       0000000000000008  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     4
  [26] .comment          PROGBITS         0000000000000000  00001030
       000000000000002c  0000000000000001  MS       0     0     1
```

Sure enough, `.data` lives *in memory* at `601028` to `601028+8 = 601030`. Subtracting `value`'s address from this section's address, we get:

```
  60102c       Address of `value`
- 601028       Start address of .data section
--------
       4
```

Thus, `value` is at offset 4 from the start of the `.data` section. Now, where in the file is the `.data` section?  That's what the `Offset` column tells us.  `.data` begins at file offset `1028`.  Knowing this, we can find the file offset of `value`:

```
  1028         File offset of .data section
+    4         Offset of `value` in .data section
-------
  102c         File offset of `value`
```

---

We've got our file offset, now let's make sure we know what to expect.  Your variable has the value 1337.  In hex, that's 0x539.  But, we need to bring up [*byte order*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) (or "endianness").  Intel x86 systems are *little endian*. That means when an integer larger than one byte is stored at an address, the *least-signifiant* byte (or "little" end) of the value is at that address, and the remaining bytes are at subsequent (increasing address).

So your 1337 will be stored (as a 4-byte `int`) in the file like this:

```
39 05 00 00
```

On a "big endian" system (e.g. Motorola 68k), the value would be seen in the file in the opposite order:

```
00 00 05 39
```

---

That all said, if you open your ELF file in a hex editor, an go to offset 102c, you will see your value:

[image]

ELF files have no checksum or CRC, so you should be able to simply edit that value in your hex editor, and it will have the new value when your program executes!

Comment: thanks for the fast reply, i understood the first part, can you explain more about the three steps, thanks.

Comment: @Mustapha Hopefully my answer fully explains how we got to our goal.

Comment: thanks a lot Jonathon, you helped me a lot today, i appreciate it mate.

Comment: Bit late to the party but thanks, it's the only clear explanation I've found of how symbol values translate to file offset!