# how to modify global variable in elf file in C

Tags: c, memory, elf

I would like to modify the value of a global variable in an elf file i.e.

int variable = 10;

I see that first I would have to open the elf file. This answer has a short program to open up an elf file,

[finding integer declared variables in ELF executable using a hex editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20671194/finding-integer-declared-variables-in-elf-executable-using-a-hex-editor)

then I would've to find the virtual address of the global variable using maybe readelf as in this other solution

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20671194/finding-integer-declared-variables-in-elf-executable-using-a-hex-editor](http://%20%20[1]:%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20671194/finding-integer-declared-variables-in-elf-executable-using-a-hex-editor)

but instead of modifying the variable using a hex editor, I want to edit it in C using the Section header(Sdhr) struct members from the elf.h file. Hopefully my question makes sense...

Comment: Your question does make sense but it is a bit too broad to be answered concisely. Suggest using libelf from [elfutils](https://sourceware.org/elfutils/) to read and write the elf data.

Comment: Well, go ahead and try it.

Comment: thanks for the answers. I just found this book https://www.dbooks.org/libelf-by-example-1587/read/ l think its intended for the same library. might be a good starting point...

Comment: @kaylum does elfutils work on Ubuntu? or is it just intended for Red Hat only?

Comment: elfutils doesn't care about the specific Linux distro. If it is Linux then it will almost certainly work.

Comment: @kaylum hey thanks. I was able to install elf utils this morning. I was wondering if there is a wiki or any other documentation on how to use elfutils. I couldn't find much so far. I would really appreciate it.